# MATLAB Vector of elements x(i) or y(i) with max(abs(x),abs(y))

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, vector

Sorry for the title, couldn't think of a concise way to phrase the problem.  I need to write a MATLAB one-liner that gives you a vector of elements z(i) where z(i) is the element x(i) or y(i) given by max(abs(x(i)),abs(y(i))).  I.e, z is the vector whose elements are the ith elements of x or y which has the maximum absolute value.

I have

```
max(abs(x),abs(y))
```

But this obviously gives you a vector of the greatest absolute values.  This is close to what I want, but I need to get the sign back of the original vector.  I'm not sure how to do this on a single line.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` vectors of identical dimensions (say, column vectors of length `n`)?

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that; x, y, z are of identical length.

Comment: If you are interested in a generic code for a number of 2D matrices, check out [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25878726/3293881)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the assumption that `x` and `y` are arrays (not necessarily vectors) of identical dimensions, you can use logical indexing:

```
(abs(x)>=abs(y)).*x + (abs(x)<abs(y)).*y
```

For information, `abs(x)>=abs(y)` is a logical array for which, for all valid indices, the `k`th component is

- `1` if `x(k)` is greater than or equal to `y(k)`,
- `0` otherwise.

---

Example:

```
>>  x = [4;7;-1;9;6];
>>  y = [5;2;-3;9;3];
>>  (abs(x)>=abs(y)).*x + (abs(x)<abs(y)).*y

ans =

     5
     7
    -3
     9
     6
```

Comment: Maybe you should have made at least one element in y bigger than the corresponding element in x, then it would be easier to see that your code works fine.

Comment: and also some negative values. It was part of the problem after all ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a generic code that you could use when working with a number of 2D matrices, let's say `x`, `y` and `p`, you can try this -

```
x = [-2 4 1;
    4 -3 2]
y = [8 -3 -5;
    -9 1 5]
p = [6 8 6;
    7 -1 -2]

mats = cat(3,x,y,p);%// concatenate all identically sized 2D matrices into 3D

[m,n] = size(x);%// get size
[maxval,dim3ind] = max(abs(mats),[],3);%// Max abs values and indices across dim3
mats_sign = sign(mats); %// signum values
out = mats_sign((dim3ind-1)*m*n + bsxfun(@plus,[1:m]',[0:n-1]*m)).*maxval %// output
```

Output -

```
x =
    -2     4     1
     4    -3     2
y =
     8    -3    -5
    -9     1     5
p =
     6     8     6
     7    -1    -2
out =
     8     8     6
    -9    -3     5
```

So, if you would like to include one more 2D matrix say `q` into the mix, just edit the first line of code -

```
mats = cat(3,x,y,p,q);
```